# Extjs - combobox Submit value

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, submit

Before ill ask my question I sould mention that i read every post about this problem.
I am submitting my extjs form using: `form.getForm().getValues()` in an independent ajax request.

I cant submit my value (userManager_userId) in a combo to to the server:

```
       new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            name: 'userManager_userName',
            valueField: 'userManager_userId',
            hiddenValue : 'userManager_userId',//I want to send this ti the server (Integer)
            displayField: 'userManager_userName'
            ....
    )}
```

The combo providing/submitting its display and not its value.
I should mention that when the for loads, I charge it with data from the server by using a `Ext.data.JsonReader`
Thanks

**Update**

So I did a little test for you to see live:
http://fatnjazzy.byethost8.com/
you can view source to see the js source.
Ill post it here when we are done.
Now it is working but the form does not initial its values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `hiddenName` property set for your combo box?When you use `hiddenValue`, you need to make use of `hiddenName`. `hiddenValue` just sets the default value for the combo. By setting it you will not be able to send the value to the server side.

**Update:** Since you are using separate Ajax request to submit the form, why are you using hidden field to store the values? you could access the value of the combo box from:

```
 comboObject.getValue()
```

Another possible reason why your form.getForm.getValues() do not give the combo's values will be due to having wrong value in `valueField`. In your case you have userManager_userId. Is that your underlying data value name to bound to the ComboBox? Here is my example:

```
store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields:['item','value'],                            
    data: [
            {item:'Option 1',value: 'OP1'},
            {item:'Option 2',value: 'OP2'},
            {item:'Option 3',value: 'OP3'}
        ]                   
}),
mode: 'local',
editable: false, 
allowBlank: false,
forceSelection: true,
valueField: 'value',
displayField: 'item',
name:'tt',
id: 'tt'
```

Here the valueField's value is bound to my store's value field..

Comment: If i add a `hiddenName:'userId'` it submits an empty string

Comment: Thanks, accessing my `obj.getValue()` will provide an empty string. same as the `getForm().getValues()`. I use the hiddenValue since I thought that this is what is suppose to be sent to the server... I removed my hiddenValue and still i get an empty string....

Answer (score 3):

Use **hiddenName** in place of or in addition to **name**. This will create a hidden field of that name which will store the value of the current selection's **valueField**. Also note that the **hiddenValue** config is for setting the initial value of the hidden field and is not a field name declaration.

Here is an altered ComboBox definition which will submit the value of the selected record's **userManager_userId** field through a request parameter of **userId**:

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    hiddenName: 'userId',
    valueField: 'userManager_userId',
    displayField: 'userManager_userName',
    // ...
});
```

Comment: If i add a `hiddenName:'userId'` it submits an empty string

Comment: The value of hiddenName is merely the parameter name the ComboBox's selected value will be stored in when submitting or calling getValues on the surrounding form. If no value is getting into that parameter then there may be other issues to resolve. A more complete example of your ComboBox definition - including especially how you have set up your store - would help tremendously.